# Give group of rows a numeric value and increment for every next group

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have created a table with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BatchTest](
    [Col1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Col3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BatchId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BatchTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have been wondering if CTEs can be used to achieve this: 
Set value of BatchId column to a fixed number for the first group of records, and then for every next group the value of BatchId should be : prev. group's number + 1.. and so on

group by clause: Col1,Col2, Col3

Result:

```
A   B   C   34
A   B   C   34
A   B   C   34
A   B   C   34

A   B   D   35
A   B   D   35
A   B   D   35
A   B   D   35

A   B   E   36
A   B   E   36
A   B   E   36
A   B   E   36
```

Start no. 34 in this case. and so on increment it for next group of records. start no is input by user.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This sounds like an X Y Problem. http://xyproblem.info
What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Also, showing us the table DDL is a good first step to asking your question, but we need to see the code that's actually using the table to be able to help you.

Comment: Well, I tried some queries but it is not worth adding in the description as they didn't give results anywhere near to what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the beginning BatchId is specified by the user, you can use a variable to modify the value of the `DENSE_RANK()` function. Using your data set, slightly randomized to show `DENSE_RANK()` working, I inserted the following:

```
INSERT INTO BatchTest
(
    Col1
    ,Col2
    ,Col3
    ,BatchId
)
VALUES 
('A','B','C',0),
('A','B','C',0),
('A','B','E',0),
('A','B','C',0),
('A','B','D',0),
('A','B','D',0),
('A','B','D',0),
('A','B','C',0),
('A','B','E',0),
('A','B','E',0),
('A','B','D',0),
('A','B','E',0)
```

Then you can use a variable for the BatchId starting value and modify Zohar's final query to be an `UPDATE`, like this, using a CTE to generate the BatchId value and then `JOIN`ing the CTE to BatchTest:

```
DECLARE @BatchId INT = 34

;WITH BatchedIds AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID
        , Col1
        , Col2
        , Col3
        , BatchId = ( DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3 )) + @BatchId - 1
    FROM BatchTest
)
UPDATE bt
SET bt.BatchId = bi.BatchId
FROM BatchTest bt
INNER JOIN BatchedIds bi ON bi.ID = bt.ID
```

Then you can query BatchTest and get these results:

```
SELECT * FROM BatchTest
ORDER BY BatchId

ID  Col1    Col2    Col3    BatchId
4   A       B       C       34
1   A       B       C       34
2   A       B       C       34
8   A       B       C       34
5   A       B       D       35
6   A       B       D       35
7   A       B       D       35
11  A       B       D       35
12  A       B       E       36
9   A       B       E       36
10  A       B       E       36
3   A       B       E       36
```

Comment: Oh, my bad! Missed that trick with the variable -1. Thanks @digital.aaron! This helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure I understand the question buy I think you are looking for `dense_rank`:

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO BatchTest (Col1, Col2, Col3, BatchId) VALUES
('1', '1', '1', 0),
('1', '1', '2', 0),
('1', '1', '3', 0),
('1', '1', '1', 0),
('1', '1', '2', 0),
('1', '1', '3', 0);
```

Query:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, BatchId, Id, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3) As DR
FROM BatchTest
ORDER BY DR
```

Results:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    BatchId Id  DR
1       1       1       0       1   1
1       1       1       0       4   1
1       1       2       0       5   2
1       1       2       0       2   2
1       1       3       0       3   3
1       1       3       0       6   3
```

Comment: Thanks! I did think of DENSE_RANK() but then it doesn't allow choosing starting number for the first group identified and then increment number for every next group. Besides, BatchId column is the one which needs to be updated.